# Opening a file on browser that is received as a ReadableStream

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm building an API on Node.js that receives some parameters and the server generates a PDF file with said parameters and I want **the browser to open the generated file**.

The file is generated successfully but I don't know how to open the file on the browser that is received as a **ReadableStream** object.

It's my first time working with ReadableStream so I don't know what the best way to handle this is.

My `app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));

//import the function to generate the PDF file
const pdf = require('./pdf');

app.post("/pdf", async (req, res) => {
    const parameterData = req.body
    
    await pdf(parameterData);
    //We create the ReadableStream from the generated file
    
    var data = fs.createReadStream('./test/output.pdf');
    var stat = fs.statSync('./test/output.pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=output.pdf');
    data.pipe(res); 
   
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
```

My `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>POST DEMO</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <button>PDF</button>
</body>

<script>
    
    const paramData = {
        //object that contains the parameters
    }

    document.querySelector('button')
        .addEventListener('click', (e) => {      
            fetch('/pdf', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(paramData)
            })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.body)
                    //This is where I would want to create the logic to open the file on the browser
                })
        });
</script>
```

I can confirm on my browser that the ReadableStream object is received on the Network tab when opening the DevTools and checking the Response

Comment: What about `res.download('./test/output.pdf')`?

Comment: `I want the browser to open the generated file` - this could easily be accomplished by simply posting the form using a `<form>` tag, and letting the browser display the response.  Is using ajax necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Blob - this should get the result you want.

```
 .then((res) => {
        return res.blob();
    })
    .then((blob) => {
        const blobData = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(blobData, '_blank');
    })
```

Comment: This does work, it opens the pdf on browser just like I needed, thank you